# How to resolve SyntaxError: Unexpected token '||=' if have it no where in my project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, pnpm, turborepo

I have an issue then running `pnpm run build` on Turborepo. I get this issue and I read also about. It is assuming that I am using '||=' operator but I am not. I search my whole Project but I couldn't find these files or this operator.

```
> ui@0.0.0 build C:\Users\anonym\Documents\dev\saas\bk-hub\packages\ui
> tsup

[31mSyntaxError: Unexpected token '||='
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:145:18)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:67:21)[39m
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

If you need something please tell me. I am hard stucked and that's reason I don't know what kind of files I should show.

I hope you could help me.

Best regards
Knome

Comment: Can you try to delete `node_modules` dir and run `npm i`

Comment: @kennarddh I deleted all node_modules and run pnpm install. Could it be that pnpm store has a bug?

Comment: What is your node js version?

Comment: @kennarddh ok thank you it was the node version I had 14.7, now I use 19.7

Comment: `||=` this operator is added on nodejs 15